# Getting an error on If not isempty

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to sort through a data column on one sheet and skip past the empty cells and copy the non empty cells and paste them into another sheet. I had this code working, and just recently I started getting error 1004. I believe that ".select" is causing the error. I am not well versed in objects, but that may be the way to go?

Does anyone know of a better way to go about doing it?

```
Sub PopulateList()

With ActiveWorkbook
Worksheets("Create Appointments").Select
[A4:J100].Clear
End With

'Two Week Follow Up
    With ActiveWorkbook
    Worksheets("All Current Projects").Select
    'Column L has Install Dates
    [L4].Select
    End With

Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("L4:L80").Cells
If Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then
        'Only move values that occurred after today
        If Cell.Value >= Now() Then
            'Once Values are found, move them to CreateAppointments sheet
            Worksheets("Create Appointments").Select
                Range("F3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cell.Value + 14 
        End If
End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50371980/edit) your post and format your code.

Comment: You need a `.` in between activeworkbook and worksheets???  Which select is erroring?  You are not using `with` properly either

Comment: I am getting the error "Application defined or object defined error" at the line: Range("F3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cell.Value + 14

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Your title suggests it's your `If Not IsEmpty(Cell) Then` line but you state you think it's a line further down in your code. Which one is highlighted when you hit "Debug" upon receiving the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a little bit and took out the IsEmpty:

```
Sub PopulateList()

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("A4:J100").Clear

'Two Week Follow Up
'Column L has Install Dates

Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Range("L4:L80")
    If Cell.Value <> 0 Then
        'Only move values that occurred after today
        If Cell.Value >= Now() Then
            'Once Values are found, move them to CreateAppointments sheet
            Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("F3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cell.Value + 14
        End If
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error at the line "Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("F3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cell.Value + 14"
DO I need to take a look at my permissions or references?

Comment: Is "F3" empty? If "F3" is empty, going down will get you to the last row, and you won't be able to offset it.

Comment: @VincentG That's a good point, for that reason I often use Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0), maybe try that

Comment: "F3" is the header row. It's a not Table, but just a cell that labels the data that will go beneath it.

I am now getting, "Run Time Error 13, Type Mismatch" although I have not changed a thing

Comment: So I am getting an error only when the line says ".End(xlDown)"
I am able to get it to work in a way by using ".End(xlUp)"

Answer (score 0):

"With ActiveWorkbook Worksheets("All Current Projects").Select"

try `ActiveWorkbook.sheets("All Current Projects")`

Answer (score 0):

First things first. Stop using `.Select`. `.Select` is something humans do. Your code doesn't need to "Select" a cell. A quick rewrite:

This may or may not solve your problem since it's unclear what is throwing that error:

```
Sub PopulateList()
    Dim Cell As Range

    Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("A4:J100").ClearContents

    For Each Cell In Worksheets("All Current Projects").Range("L4:L80").Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(Cell.Value) Then
                'Only move values that occurred after today
                If Cell.Value >= Now() Then
                    'Once Values are found, move them to CreateAppointments sheet
                    Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("F3").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Value = Cell.Value + 14 
                End If
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error at the line "Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("F3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cell.Value + 14"

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line by placing the cursor on the line and hitting F9. Then run your code. Each iteration it will stop there and you will have to F5 to make it run the line and continue on. Keep an eye on your Locals pane (View>>Locals if it's not open already). Open up "Cell" and look at the "Value" to see what it is. Either xlDown is ending up at row 1000000 and can't offset down one more row or `cell.value` doesn't contain a number and so it can't add "14" to it. (That's my guess anyway).

Comment: You might have luck switching to `Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("F99999").End(xlUp).Value = Cell.value + 14`

Comment: I did not know about F9 and Local window, so thank you for pointing me in that direction. Its very helpful.

Comment: Same as I commented above: I am getting an error only when the line says ".End(xlDown)"
I am able to get it to work in a way by using ".End(xlUp)"

Answer (score 0):

The xlDown is not finding the next empty space correctly, is better to find it with xlUp.

Note: This code assumes that after clearing A4:J100 there is no more data on Column F after F3

Edit: I changed the range on my testing, changed the range to reflect yours.

```
Sub PopulateList()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Create Appointments").Range("A4:J100").Clear
    'Two Week Follow Up
    'Column L has Install Dates
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Worksheets("All Current Projects").Range("L4:L80")
        If Cell.Value <> 0 Then
            'Only move values that occurred after today
            If Cell.Value >= Now() Then
                'Once Values are found, move them to CreateAppointments sheet
                'This assumes that after clearing Range A4:J100 there is no more data under F3
                Worksheets("Create Appointments").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Cell.Value + 14
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate your error, when the very last cell of column F is filled.
Also Ricardo A mentioned above:
"Note: This code assumes that after clearing A4:J100 there is no more data on Column F after F3"

You could check with:

```
Debug.Print Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F3").End(xlDown).Address
```